# IQueryCollection.ToList() combines values unwantedly

Tags: c#, ienumerable, iqueryable, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

My project uses two libraries:

- Swashbuckle.ASPNetCore
- FluentValidation

Im writing a validator interceptor to do some additional checks that are needed seperately from the validator: `MyModelValidator : AbstractValidator<MyModel>`

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public List<string> Date { get; set; }
}

public class PrefixValidatorInterceptor : IValidatorInterceptor {
    public IValidationContext BeforeAspNetValidation(ActionContext acionContext, IValidationContext commonContext) {...}
}
```

The object that arrives in the `BeforeAspNetValidation` function is the `MyModel` object, with for example a list of two values for this request: [http://localhost:{{port}}/api/endpoint?City=New York&Date=02-05-2020&Date=07-27-2021](http://localhost:%7B%7Bport%7D%7D/api/endpoint?City=New%20York&Date=02-05-2020&Date=07-27-2021)

```cs
commonContext.InstanceToValidate.City = "New York"
commonContext.InstanceToValidate.Date[0] = "02-05-2020"
commonContext.InstanceToValidate.Date[1] = "07-27-2021"
```

Now I want to store this object as a Dictionary/List to validate it

```cs
List<KeyValuePair<string, StringValues>> getRequestValues = actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Query.ToList();
```

But this will combine the values with a comma separator.

```cs
getRequestValues[0] = { "City", "New York" }
getRequestValues[1] = { "Date", "02-05-2020,07-27-2021" }
```

Instead, I want it to look like this:

```cs
getRequestValues[0] = { "City", "New York" }
getRequestValues[1] = { "Date", "02-05-2020" }
getRequestValues[2] = { "Date", "07-27-2021" }
```

Alternatively, a list with just the values is also acceptable:

```cs
anotherList[0] = "New York"
anotherList[1] = "02-05-2020"
anotherList[2] = "07-27-2021"
```

You cant just split the strings on the comma character as the value might contain a comma itself, so that option doesn't seem viable.

I know that the `HttpContext.Request.Query` (`IQueryCollection`) makes use of the `StringValues : IList<string>` type
for the values so calling `.ToList()` on it is part of the .NET Core 3.1 Enummerable class so that cant really be changed.

One solution I thought of is to use reflection on the object that gets set in
`IValidationContext.InstanceToValidate` and loop through all its fields and manually build up the `List<>`.

Is there a better way?

I tried `.ToList();` and `.ToDictionary();` but both will combine the date values with a comma separator.

Comment: Actually you _can_ split on the comma, it is specifically a CSV formatted list of values that will need to be escaped if you were to include a comma in the actual values.

Comment: what is the data in your `actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Query`?
I think the data send from frontend is already contain the string `02-05-2020,07-27-2021`

Comment: The request I make is `http://localhost:{{port}}/api/endpoint?City=New York&Date=02-05-2020&Date=07-27-2021`, the `InstanceToValidate` object of type MyModel has them separated like I described in my question. Technically the `StringValues` type is also a list, but the values get combined when calling `.ToList()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the following will do:

```
var getRequestValues = new List<string>();
foreach (var field in context.HttpContext.Request.Query)
{
    foreach (var value in field.Value)
    {
        getRequestValues.Add(value);
    }
}
```

`.Query` is an `IQueryCollection` and loop-able, and the `.Value` that comes out of it is the type `StringValues`, which implements `IList<string>`, so is also loop-able.

This works and doesnt require additional reflection.